# What is the performance of leftOuterJoin in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

If I perform A.leftOuterJoin(B) where A is a RDD[(K, V)] that has 1 billion elements and B is a RDD[(K, W)] that has 1000 elements, does Spark still copy each of the 1 billion elements of A to the new RDD?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I looked at the internal code the Join was based on coGroup().

Essentially, both RDDs will be shuffled (across the network) by their keys, then a hash join will happen in local memory for each key. If for any reason the partitioning is already by your key, no additional shuffle will happen.

As for "copy the elements" I don't think so, local pointers should be copied, but intermediate results from the previous stage are not stored unless you persist them manually.